# How can I grant execute on dbms_crypto to a user?

Tags: database, oracle

When I try to execute this:

```
grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to "DB_Project";
```

I get this  error:

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

[image: Attempt and error when granting execute on sys.dbms_crypto to another user]

I also tried this:

```
grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to SYSTEM."DB_Project";
```

But I get this  error:

> ERROR: 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

How to solve???

Comment: Try always to avoid double quotes in oracle. Without the double-quotes, oracle  will assume uppercase names regardless if you write with upper or lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect as SYS and grant that privilege to a user:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> grant execute on dbms_crypto to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

You granted it to `"DB_Project"` - did you really create user using mixed case? If not, remove double quotes.

Saying that you'd grant it to "user created inside SYSTEM" - what would that be? Users can't be created "inside" other users, each of them is separate. I'm trying to do what you told us:

```
SQL> create user "DB_Project" identified by test;

User created.

SQL> grant execute on dbms_crypto to db_project;
grant execute on dbms_crypto to db_project
                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01917: user or role 'DB_PROJECT' does not exist


SQL> grant execute on dbms_crypto to "DB_Project";

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Apparently, it works when username is enclosed into double quotes (if it was created that way - I wouldn't recommend it, though).

Is there anything else you did (and didn't show us)? What caused ORA-00942? There's no *table* involved here ...

Oh, yes - saying that "you can't find user" - here's how you'd do that:

```
SQL> select * From all_users;

USERNAME                          USER_ID CREATED
------------------------------ ---------- --------
XS$NULL                        2147483638 29.05.14
DB_Project                             49 17.03.19
SCOTT                                  48 19.02.19
APEX_040000                            47 29.05.14
<snip>
```

Comment: I did  everything as you recommend But whatever same problem:(((


For ex: grant execute on dbms_crypto to scott;

--------------------------------------------------------

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: As I said: **connect as SYS**. It seems you're connected as SYSTEM.

Comment: Dude, can you send me your what's app number, In case if I have some problem in terms of database I'll ask you!? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're welcome. As of contacting me, I like to keep private information *private*. If you have any problems, feel free to ask here and someone will assist (me included).